# How can I assess how sweet the water of a young coconut in husk will be before buying/opening the coconut?

Tags: flavor, fruit, coconut, sweet

How can I assess how sweet the water of a young coconut in husk will be before buying/opening the coconut?

Example of a young coconut in husk:

[image]

Comment: you probably can't, other than checking for freshness and the quality of the store you buy it from.

Comment: @Max thanks, how does freshness correlate with sweetness?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment and also based on some personal discussions, there is no way to assess how sweet the water of a young coconut in husk will be before opening the coconut. It's a hit and miss, unless one can track its age and provenance (which may be rather challenging when buying the coconut far from its tree, e.g. in my case buying in the US).

From https://eatdelights.com/coconut-water-taste/:

> Generally, it is sweet, but in most cases, the taste differs depending on where the palm tree is grown, the saline content in the soil, the climate, and proximity to the sea.

From https://coconuthandbook.tetrapak.com/chapter/chemistry-coconut-water:

> Between 7-9 months, the sweetness of coconut water increases to its maximum when sugar content increases. From 10-13 months, the sugar levels decrease and coconut water tastes less sweet. This is represented by total soluble solids (°Brix).